# how to to create custom & composite view in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I would like to create a custom and composite view in android. My custom view will include 1 textview, 5 radiobuttons two buttons and some images. I don't know how to do it. if there would be some example or code spinet, it would be nice..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it could help you:

First you can define a RelativeLayout in xml, with all the elements you want on it, placed like you want.

Second, when you have that layout defined, you can develop a custom class, extending RelativeLayout, and inflate that layout in the constructor method of the class, something like this:

```
public class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout {

 ...

 public MyCustomView(Context context) {

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null));

  oneTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneTextView);
  oneRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.oneRadioButton);
  ...
 }
 ...
}
```

At this point, you can use oneTextView, oneRadioButton, etc., in your class in a normal way.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but would I not end up with *two* RelativeLayouts this way? After all, the inflater creates a new Relative Layout that is then added to this, another RelativeLayout?

Comment: In that case you can add the <merge> element inside your_layout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#merge-element

Answer (score 2):

you might want to read about the extended class' constructors here:
[Do I need all three constructors for an Android custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195713/do-i-need-all-three-constructors-for-an-android-custom-view?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) to get started.

Comment: thanks, I read it, but couldn't figure out what actually i want. Like I would add simple animation in the view.