# How to solve "Implementation restriction: trait ... accesses protected method ... inside a concrete trait method."

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, mixins, protected, traits

A Java library class I'm using declares

```java
protected getPage(): Page { ... }
```

Now I want to make a helper Scala mixin to add features that I often use. I don't want to extend the class, because the Java class has different subclasses I want to extend at different places. The problem is that if I use `getPage()` in my mixin `trait`, I get this error:

> Implementation restriction: trait `MyMixin` accesses protected method `getPage` inside a concrete trait method.

**Is there a solution how to make it work, without affecting my subclasses?** And why is there this restriction?

---

So far, I came up with a work-around: I override the method in the trait as

```
override def getPage(): Page = super.getPage();
```

This seems to work, but I'm not completely satisfied. Luckily I don't need to override `getPage()` in my subclasses, but if I needed, I'd get two overrides of the same method and this work-around won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that even though the trait extends the Java class, the implementation is not actually in something that extends the Java class.  Consider

```
class A { def f = "foo" }
trait T extends A { def g = f + "bar" }
class B extends T { def h = g + "baz" }
```

In the actual bytecode for `B` we see

```
public java.lang.String g();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokestatic    #17; //Method T$class.g:(LT;)Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   areturn
```

which means it just forwards to something called `T$class`, which it turns out is

```
public abstract class T$class extends java.lang.Object{
public static java.lang.String g(T);
  Code:
  ...
```

So the body of the code isn't called from a subclass of `A` at all.

Now, with Scala that's no problem because it just omits the `protected` flag from bytecode.  But `Java` enforces that only subclasses can call protected methods.

And thus you have the problem, and the message.

You cannot easily get around this problem, though the error message suggests what is perhaps the best alternative:

```
public class JavaProtected {
  protected int getInt() { return 5; }
}

scala> trait T extends JavaProtected { def i = getInt }
<console>:8: error: Implementation restriction: trait T accesses
      protected method getInt inside a concrete trait method.
  Add an accessor in a class extending class JavaProtected as a workaround.
```

Note the last line.

```
class WithAccessor extends JavaProtected { protected def myAccessor = getInt }
trait T extends WithAccessor { def i = myAccessor }
```

works.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to avoid, adding accessors to my subclasses. But now I understand why it isn't possible.

Comment: @PetrPudlák - You don't have to add accessors to _every_ subclass, just to _one_ accessor-enabling subclass of the original.  Then all the other ones that mix in the trait will extend the accessor-enabling class instead of the original.  (Of course, the protected accessors will be part of the interface, but at least you'll only have to write them once.)

Comment: The problem is that I want to mix in the trait to Java classes whose only common superclass is in the Java library. This is why I wanted to use the mixin trait, to add functionality without having to create a Scala subclass for each of the Java classes I extend.

Comment: @PetrPudlák - Ah.  Well, reflection (in an environment without a restrictive security manager) would allow it.  Pick the method out, call `.setAccessible(true)`, `invoke` it, cast to the right type.  I do not recommend this at all.