# Android Cropping Drawable from top to fit ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

**Problem Description:**
I have an ImageView which changes in size due to changing heights of different devices.

**Aim:**
I am looking to keep the bottom edge of the drawable in line with the bottom of the image view and crop the rest from the top.

**What I've Done:**
I've tried using centerCrop but it only crops from top and bottom:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llHomeScreenButtonBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_home" />
```

I've also tried copying the Extended ImageView class from: [Chris Arriola](https://gist.github.com/arriolac/3843346)

However, I've encountered an error from eclipse saying:

> Custom view CustomImageView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work

The XML code fragment looks like this:

```
    <com.misc.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llHomeScreenButtonBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
        android:src="@drawable/bg_home" />
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement the 2- and 3-argument constructors.

The one-argument constructor `public CustomImageView(Context)` can't be used by the XML inflation process..  XML inflation uses one of the other two constructors, with one or two more arguments.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195858/357951