# Using Android support design library on custom view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library, android-support-design

I have a custom RelativeLayout and want to use the android support design library inside it (so I can use the CoordinatorLayout). I've tried adding

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

but am still getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

Does this mean that I cannot use it on a custom view and only inside an Activity?
Because I cannot use an activity here. I'm adding this view to the WindowManager.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please copy your custom RelativeLayout code.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem. It's constructed correctly, just like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22780035/5712208)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are adding the view with WindowManager and a Theme.AppCompat compatible theme is needed, you just need to set your theme before calling your LayoutInflater.
For example: `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);`
It should work :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to add a `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` to my custom keyboard. I solved the problem with:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)

    super.onCreate()
}
```

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Instead, [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).