# Using CardView as Compound View base

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, layout-inflater

I'm trying to create a `CardView` layout which will be re-used to display a tweet on the profile page and in a `RecyclerView` on the home page. The difference is that the `RecyclerView` will inflate the layout itself and the profile page will use a custom view.

However, when using the custom view on the profile page it creates an additional `CardView` behind it. My best guess is that this happens because the custom view extends from the `CardView` class and the `RecyclerView` of course does not extend this class.

So what I end up with is a `CardView` with my layout inside of it like shown on the image below:
[layout in CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06m67.png)

While in the `RecyclerView` it looks as it should:
[layout inflated in RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4x4p.png)

I also tried extending the custom-view class with `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` instead of `CardView` but with the `CardView` still as the root in `tweet.xml`. This got rid of the problem partially, but even with `setClipToPadding(false)` and `setClipChilderen(false)` it still would cut of part of the `CardView`'s shadow border.

I have tried extending from `CardView` while having the root in `tweet.xml` be a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` and doing styling inside Java. <s>But this resulted in another 'flaw' when using the card radius dimen value with `setRadius(R.dimen.card_corner_radius)` (which was 8dp). And I ended up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9flIA.png).</s>

So how do I keep the `CardView` as the root in my `xml` file while using it as a custom-view?

`tweet.xml` [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNjBO.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="8dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_spacing_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_spacing_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_spacing_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    style="@style/CardView">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_image"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <!-- Rest of layout -->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`TweetView.java`

```
public class TweetView extends CardView {

    public TweetView(Context context) {
        this(context, null /* attrs */);
    }

    public TweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.style.AppTheme);
    }

    public TweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet, this);
    }
}
```

`fragment_profile.xml` [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL4DR.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ProfileFragment">

    <nl.robinpfeiffer.parrot.twitter.views.TweetView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT

I tried changing the code of `TweetView.java` like @Eminem suggested. But the [CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06m67.png) still stays the same; nested in another `CardView`.

`TweetView.java` Updated

```
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public TweetView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}

public TweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}

public TweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet, this, true);
}
```

EDIT 2:

I didn't pay very much attention when the java styling failed and forgot that it should have been `setRadius(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_corner_radius));` instead of `setRadius(R.dimen.card_corner_radius);`, as the latter one uses the resource integer id value for the radius. Hence the *way* too rounded corners.

Comment: by compound you mean reusable layout?

Comment: @Eminem Yes, it is used for the profile and the homescreen.

Comment: I dont get it where is your difficulty?

Comment: @Eminem In this [case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06m67.png) it creates an additional `CardView` around the layout without having specified that anywhere in the code. That is what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22780035/9025311

Comment: @Eminem So I tried that, but the problem stays the same. There is still a `CardView` around the `CardView` that my layout creates.

Comment: then remove thia ` <nl.robinpfeiffer.parrot.twitter.views.TweetView` have you tried it?I am on my mobile I will look at it later with details

Comment: @Eminem that is my layout, so I don't really see how removing it would be useful since I then don't have the compound-view anymore. And thus leaving me with an empty fragment.

Comment: because when you extend it from Cardview class it already creates one but you do already in your layout file,give it a try

Comment: @Eminem I tried that but then styling via Java doens't work as well as via xml, see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9flIA.png). Anyway I think that If I just remove the `CardView` from the layout and extend the `tweet.xml` layout from `ConstriantLayout` and just put that view in a `CardView` when I need a card around it. Essentially side-stepping the problem.
OR is there an option to disable generating an extra card when extending from `CardView`?

Comment: use `merge`instead of a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally fixed it, like @Eminem suggested, with a `<merge>` tag. Because I was extending my `TweetView` class from `CardView`, it automatically creates a `CardView`. In `TweetView` the layout `tweet.xml` get's inflated via `inflate(getContext, R.layout.tweet, this)` Styling is now handeled in the `styles.xml` files by creating a custom card style. This style needs to be applied where you use the `TweetView` class.

My resulting layout and class files are as follows:

`tweet.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="android.support.v7.widget.CardView">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:focusable="true">

        <!-- Rest of internal layout -->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

`TweetView.java`

```
public class TweetView extends CardView implements Observer {

public TweetView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TweetView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.tweet, this);
}
```

`styles.xml`

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <!-- Base theme items -->
    </style>

    <style name="CardTweet" parent="CardView">
        <!-- Custom card items -->
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/card_corner_radius</item>
    </style>
```

And finally this is how I used the class in a standard `Fragment` and a `RecyclerView`:

`fragment_profile.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ProfileFragment">

        <nl.robinpfeiffer.parrot.twitter.views.TweetView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            style="@style/CardTweet"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_tweet.xml` this is a `RecyclerView` item that get's inflated in the `RecyclerViewAdapter`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nl.robinpfeiffer.parrot.twitter.views.TweetView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CardTweet"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_spacing_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_spacing_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_spacing_vertical" />
```

[Fixed card, normal layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHmcl.png)

[Fixed card, RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F2FG.png)