# Why do we need a 4th constructor for Lollipop?

Tags: java, android, view, android-5.0-lollipop

I started a project targeting Android Lollipop (21), and created a custom view. When I generated constructors for the view, I got a new 4th constructor which takes more params than the others.

```java
public class FooView extends FrameLayout {
  public FooView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public FooView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public FooView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  // This 4th constructor
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public FooView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }
}
```

My question is, why do we need it? What would happen if I remove this constructor and run the app on Lollipop?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195713/do-i-need-all-three-constructors-for-an-android-custom-view

Comment: You don't need it and nothing will happen if you remove it (see previous comment). It exists on the default Views so that you can pass in a default style resource (see answer re: docs below).

Comment: why would anyone want to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Information from [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int))

> public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
>   int defStyleRes)
>
> Added in API level 21
>
> Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style from
>   a theme attribute or style resource. This constructor of View allows
>   subclasses to use their own base style when they are inflating.
>
> When determining the final value of a particular attribute, there are
>   four inputs that come into play:
>
> 1. Any attribute values in the given AttributeSet.
> 2. The style resource specified in the AttributeSet (named "style").
> 3. The default style specified by defStyleAttr.
> 4. The default style specified by defStyleRes.
> 5. The base values in this theme.
>
> Each of these inputs is considered in-order, with the first listed
>   taking precedence over the following ones. In other words, if in the
>   AttributeSet you have supplied  , then
>   the button's text will always be black, regardless of what is
>   specified in any of the styles.
>
> Parameters
>
> - context The Context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.
> - attrs   The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
> - defStyleAttr    An attribute in the current theme that contains a reference to a style resource that supplies default values for the
>     view. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.
> - defStyleRes A resource identifier of a style resource that supplies default values for the view, used only if defStyleAttr is 0 or can not
>     be found in the theme. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.