# Android: Set style programmatically to custom button

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, android-button

I have an custom view which extends Button. And I just want to set the belove style to this view.

```
    <style name="MultipleButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.Spinner.Underlined">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>
```

To be able set style programmatically, I have tried some way. But They didn't work for me.

**The First way**, is using the style in the constructor of the custom button like this :

```
public class SpinnerButton extends AppCompatButton{

public SpinnerButton (Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.style.MultipleButtonStyle);

    }
}
```

**Second way** is use `setTextAppearance` method. It didn't work me as well.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        super.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.MultipleButtonStyle );
    } else {
        super.setTextAppearance(R.style.MultipleButtonStyle);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

your constructor looks fine, are you overriding also other ones (e.g. this with `AttributeSet`, which is called when inflating from XML)? check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195713/do-i-need-all-three-constructors-for-an-android-custom-view) question about `View`s constructors and some styling

second way is improper, because `parent` of your style is a style for whole `Spinner.Underlined`, not only for `TextAppearance`. in this case you should extend `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium` (or other). if you choose this way then remember about deprecated [setTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(android.content.Context,%20int)) method in API23 and you may use some helper without checking OS version:

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

Comment: I don't call the constructor from XML. the custom view is created dynamically from the java layer.  Beside, I was supposing setTextAppearance set whole style for a view. Thanks allot. Your explanation explains why the ways don't work for me. However, I don't know how can I draw a button as a spinner.