# How to extend Android Chronometer?

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I want to extend Chronometer class and add my code.

How I could do it?
I tried, but I can't get Chronometer constructor with View field. I get an exception, it is obvious:

```
...
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.mantas.test.ChronometerV2
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
...
```

My code:

```
public class ChronometerV2 extends Chronometer{
    public ChronometerV2(Contex context){
        super(contex);
    }
}
```

and initiation:

```
ChronometerV2 c2 = findViewById(R.id.chronometerv2);
```

I am passing View here, but Chronometer only has constructor with Context field. How to do it?

Comment: You did not override the two-parameter constructor. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9195713/115145) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this constructor:

```
public ChronometerV2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```