# When you change attributes in an xml file, which constructor of custom view is called?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

I am creating my own `custom view`.

Here is the code for MyCustomView.java

```
    package com.krish.customviews
    import...
    
    public class MyCustomView extends FrameLayout{
          public MyCustomView(@NonNull Context context){
               super(context);
               init();

          }
          public MyCustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs){
               super(context, attrs);
               init();

          }
          public MyCustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
               super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
               init();

          }
          private void init(){
          }
            
    }
```

And my main_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.krish.MyCustomView> 

//layout attributes


/>
```

My question is: **If I change the attributes of the custom view in the .xml file, will the 2nd or 3rd constructor of `MyCustomView.java` file be called?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described by [@Zain answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66937876/2016562) the **two-argument** constructor is called when the **layout is inflated from XML**.

- The `defStyleAttr` is the default style. It doesn’t directly point to a style, but lets you point to one of the **attributes** defined in your theme.
  If you’re subclassing a widget and not specifying **your own** default style then be sure to use the parent classes default style in your constructors (don’t just pass `0`). It can be `0` only to not look for defaults.
  For example in the `MaterialButton`:  `R.attr.materialButtonStyle`
- The `defStyleRes` is a resource identifier of a style resource that supplies default values for the view, used only if `defStyleAttr` is 0 or can not be found in the theme. Can be `0` to not look for defaults.
  For example in the `MaterialButton`: `R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Button`

The `AttributeSet` parameter can essentially be thought of as a map of the XML parameters you specify in your layout.
[Keep in mind the styling precedence order:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme#obtainStyledAttributes(android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int))

> When determining the final value of a particular attribute, there are
> four inputs that come into play:
>
> - Any attribute values in the given `AttributeSet`.
> - The style resource specified in the `AttributeSet` (named `"style"`).
> - The default style specified by `defStyleAttr` and `defStyleRes`
> - The base values in this theme.

Answer (score 2):

The two-argument constructor is the only needed when you access the custom view from XML.

```
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

The 3 & 4 argument constructors are meant to be called by super classes to provide default style via theme attribute and direct default style resource.

```
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

- The `defStyleAttr` parameter is the reference to a style attribute
  defined in the theme.
- The `defStyleRes` parameter is the reference to the default style
  defined in styles.xml. Don't worry, if this explanation is
  unsatisfying to you. I will go deeper into details in the section
  about attributes and styles.

[Source back to this article](https://medium.com/@Zielony/guide-to-android-custom-views-constructors-df47476e334c)

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195713/do-i-need-all-three-constructors-for-an-android-custom-view) question