# How can I add more pictures and text in a textview?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to add images and text in a textview.

My code:

```
txtViewNews.setText(" text "+VAR11+" text");
txtViewNews.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.a1a, 0, 0, 0);
```

It works. On left side there is the image and on the right side there is the text.

But I want to add another image and another text under the first image and text. But how?

Comment: Add another TextView. Or an ImageView.

Comment: Create custom composite `View` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258697/6950238) answer of [Victor de Francisco Domingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644339/victor-de-francisco-domingo).

Answer (score 0):

Use layout managers.  Like Linear layout with vertical orientation in a grid layout. Nested Layout.

Comment: Can you give a working example instead just two therms.

Comment: Nested layouts are to be avoided like death. Since they affect performances.

Comment: u can use a user defined adapter with a adapter view(consisting a image on left and a text on right ) + a topping with list view . where the next node consisting a similar pattern. or else u need to use a nested Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand why you need this while you can add listview which will grow when additional row will get added. Simple.